# How to calculate laser power on photodiode?

Tags: power, photodiode, output, laser

I am completely lost calculating the power of a laser diode and hope, that someone could help me.
Here is my setup:

OSRAM PL 520 (Type B1 = 50mW) Green Laser Diode

OSRAM SFH 203 Photodiode

The laser diode projects a laser beam on a photodiode with a distance of around 1,5m from laser diode to photodiode. How can I calculate the current output of the photodiode based on the data provided in the datasheets?

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Does all of the laser light hit the photodiode?

Comment: Perhaps the "Spectral sensitivity" parameter would be of some help.

Do also look at the relative spectral sensitivity value for your wavelength of the laser, perhaps even consider filtering out light of irrelevant wavelengths.

Do also keep in mind that the photodiode may not appear equally sensitive from all directions.

Comment: Yes it's fully hit

Comment: I measured the current, it's around 26µA.

But isn't there a way to calculate the current instead of measuring it?

Comment: If all the laser power is absorbed, read out the sensitivity in A/W from the datasheet and multiply. That is the current.

Comment: You are right, thanks! And if, let's say only 50% of the laser will hit the photodiode, you can multiply the value with 0,5? Or do you have to pay attention to some other parameters in that case?

Comment: @Kurtpete If half the laser power hits the diode then you get half the current. If power is uniform across the beam then half the area gets you half the current. But lasers dont typically have a uniform beam profile, gaussian is more common. So you need to do some more work, or you need to find an argument from symmetry.